# Get ID of post after creation with wp_insert_post()

Tags: wordpress

Can't seem to find a definitive answer anywhere. I need to get the ID of a post after it's created with wp_insert_post().

```
$log_item = array(
    'post_title' => $title,
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'log-item',
    'meta_input' => array(
        // 'wpcf-date-checked' => '',
        // 'wpcf-checked-by' => '',
        'wpcf-belongs-to-id' => $parent_id,
    ),
);
wp_insert_post( $log_item );
```

After that, how do I get the ID of the just created `$log_item` post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please store the post id into temporary variable :

```
     $log_item = array(
            'post_title' => $title,
            'post_content' => '',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => 'log-item',
            'meta_input' => array(
                // 'wpcf-date-checked' => '',
                // 'wpcf-checked-by' => '',
                'wpcf-belongs-to-id' => $parent_id,
            ),
        );

  //  You can also get the new post ID after inserting a new post:

            $post_id = wp_insert_post( $log_item , $wp_error );
```

For more help : [Click Here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/)